# Guitar Rig with Ltd EC-1000 sound like with $180 guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, computer

I'm playing on Guitar Rig 5. Until now, i used to play on a $180 Cort X1. Now i bought the LTD EC-1000. My problems is that I can't hear any improvement in sound. It sounds literally the same with both guitars. As an interface I use the Behringer UMC202HD (around 60 bucks).

Is there a problem with the EC-1000 or with the interface (too cheap?) or is Guitar Rig just not good?

Comment: You might experiment with changing the sampling rate in GR5 ASIO/Audio settings. This could have a slight impact on what is captured. 192kHz is overkill and potentially unwanted, 96 might give better (lower) latency. It is unclear to me what internal rate GR5 uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the Cort products, but the ESP LTD guitars like the EC-1000 aren't exactly made to have a distinct characteristic tone. The body wood and pickups tend to sound very balanced and clean and clear, as opposed to having a lot of character that you can really hear. The intention is that most of the tone will come from the amp (usually with a good amount of distortion) and the guitar will stay out of the way.

In addition to that, some amps and some software models make every guitar sound almost the same. A lot of Mesa Boogie amps, especially with the gain turned up, sound the same no matter what guitar you plug in. Some amp modeling software is like that, and even better modeling software will make all guitars sound the same if you're using a high quality model of an amp that makes all guitars sound the same.

The best way to hear a guitar's character is with a very clean sound on an amp or model that adds a little to the sound but also allows the guitar's personality to come through. A Fender Twin Reverb model or Vox AC-30 model might be good.

Also, remember that tone is only one aspect of the quality of a guitar. The intonation, comfort, and reliability are all important factors that can make a guitar expensive even if the tone is not changed at all.

Comment: Thanks again for explaining. I tried some clean stuff and yeah - it sounds better. Especially the high notes are more kind of a creaking on the cheap guitar. Also i found that if i play this tabs: (on thick e (dropped to d), a, d strings) 3-2-2-2-3-2-2-2-3-2-3-5 really fast, you can hear the individual cords way better on the EC-1000 than on the cheap one. I assume this is because of the EMG81?

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hopefully the new guitar feels better to play. I have two strats made in Mexico, a 300$ one and a 700$ one and they are "night and day" even unplugged (fretboard feel, weight, balance, sustain) but the pickups are much nicer and hotter on the more expensive one.